# Where to configure jest in a monorepo?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, monorepo

I am setting up a monorepo in which I am building a react app where I will be using typescript. We want to use jest to test backend features and React-Testing-Library to test frontend features. Should I install jest and add the config file in root or directly in the ''backend'' package?

What would be the advantage / disadvantages of doing one over the other?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10):

Just install the jest package in the root. Then, add [projects [array<string | ProjectConfig>]](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#projects-arraystring--projectconfig)
 configuration in `jest.config.js` file:

> Jest will run tests in all of the specified projects at the same time. This is great for monorepos or when working on multiple projects at the same time.

My project uses [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) to manage mono repos.

Folder structure:

```sh
⚡  tree -L 2 -I 'node_modules|examples' 
.
├── LICENSE
├── coverage
│   ├── clover.xml
│   ├── coverage-final.json
│   ├── lcov-report
│   └── lcov.info
├── jest.config.js
├── jest.setup.js
├── lerna.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── redux-saga-examples
│   └── redux-toolkit-example
└── tsconfig.json

5 directories, 10 files
```

There are two packages: `redux-saga-examples` and `redux-toolkit-example`. There are many test files in these packages.

The `package.json` in the root:

```json
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "bootstrap": "lerna bootstrap",
    "clean": "lerna clean",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "lerna": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.4"
  }
}
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
const reduxSagaExamplesPkg = require('./packages/redux-saga-examples/package.json');
const RTKExamplesPkg = require('./packages/redux-toolkit-example/package.json');

module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  projects: [
    {
      preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
      testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
      setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
      displayName: reduxSagaExamplesPkg.name,
      testMatch: ['<rootDir>/packages/redux-saga-examples/**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)'],
    },
    {
      preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
      testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
      setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
      displayName: RTKExamplesPkg.name,
      testMatch: ['<rootDir>/packages/redux-toolkit-example/**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)'],
    },
  ],
};
```

Now, you can run `npm t` npm script in the root of the project to run all tests.

Answer (score 3):

you need to create a `jest.config.js` in the root project, you have to be carefull and change the setup file for each project  in `setupFilesAfterEnv` param

with some content like this:

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  projects: [
    {
      preset: 'ts-jest',
      testEnvironment: 'node',
      displayName: 'auth',
      setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./src/auth/test/setup.ts'],
      testMatch: ['<rootDir>/src/auth/**/*.test.ts'],
    },
    {
      preset: 'ts-jest',
      testEnvironment: 'node',
      displayName: 'tickets',
      setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./src/tickets/test/setup.ts'],
      testMatch: ['<rootDir>/src/tickets/**/*.test.ts'],
    },
  ],
};
```

and have to remove jest config from `package.json` and update the scripts for each project

```
  "scripts": {
    "auth": "ts-node-dev src/auth/index.ts",
    "tickets": "ts-node-dev src/tickets/index.ts",
    "test:auth": "jest --selectProjects=auth --watchAll --no-cache",
    "test:tickets": "jest --selectProjects=tickets --watchAll --no-cache"
  }
```